# Shell Scripting and use of gawk along with arithmetic operations

Tags: bash, shell, gawk

I have a tab delimited file and I want to perform some mathematical calculations on the columns present in file.

let the file name be `sndf` and `$tag` have some integer value, I want to first find difference between the values of column 3 and 2 then divide column 4 value with the value in `$tag` again divide the resultant with the difference in values of column 3 and 2 and final result is multiplied by 100.

```
cat $sndf | gawk '{for (i = 1; i <= NF; i += 1) {
    printf "%f\t"  $3 -$2 "\t",  (((($4/"'$tag'")/($3-$2)))*100);
} printf "\n"}'>normal_wrt_region
```

the command is writing answer 4 times instead of one time to the output file..... can u all suggest an improvement?
thank you

SOLUTION: Dear all, I have solved the problem, thank you all for reading the problem and investing your time.

Comment: Can you try to give your questions a more descriptive title? Not only this question, but also a lot of your others have ambiguous titles.

Comment: What's actually the question?

Comment: ANd what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the command is writing answer 4 times instead of one time to the output file, can u all suggest an improvement?

Don't use the for loop if you don't need one?

```
cat $sndf | gawk '{ printf "%f\t"  $3 -$2 "\t", (((($4/"'$tag'")/($3-$2)))*100) }'
```

Comment: This will do something different.